# How to make lighttpd decompress bzip2 files on the fly?

Tags: compression, lighttpd

Using lighttpd, I want bzip2 some of the lesser used files on my website.

I then want lighttpd to "automatically" decompress them when someone requests them.

I *don't* want to send "Content-Type: application/bzip2" and force the client to decompress (some clients automatically save bzip2 files instead of displaying them). Instead, I want to send "Content-Type: text/html" followed by the uncompressed file contents.

I realize I could write a Perl script to do this or use a compressed filesystem, but I'm hoping for a simpler solution.

Neither "mod_compress" nor "mod_deflate" does what I want. What I actually need is more like "mod_inflate", which unfortunately doesn't exist for lighttpd.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but is too long for a comment. My ugly "solution" = in lighttpd.conf for this host:

```
  cgi.assign = (".pl" => "/usr/bin/perl",  
                ".bz2" => "/usr/local/bin/bc-page-bunzip2.pl")
```

(the .pl extension has nothing to do with it, just including it for completeness), and then make bc-page-bunzip2.pl a program that does nothing but print "`Content-type: text/html\n\n`" followed by `system("bzcat $ARGV[0]")`:

https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/BCINFO3/usr/local/bin/bc-page-bunzip2.pl